# Est-ce la description d'un personnage timide ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Comment peut-on caractériser le personnage suivant :

> Il était toujours prêt à s’écarter au passage de n’importe qui.

Est-ce qu’il est timide, timoré ? Ou y a-t-il d’autres significations ?

Comment: Sans contexte il est difficile de répondre, (il laissait passer les autres parce qu'il était poli ? gênait à cause de son embonpoint ? de son fauteuil roulant ?  souffrait de phobie sociale ? etc.) et encore avec contexte ce ne serait pas une question de langue telles que les questions sont définies dans la [FAQ](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mais de compréhension de texte. La question pourrait être reformulée pour porter sur la différence entre « timoré » et « timide ».

Comment: @Laure, merci beaucoup pour votre commentaire. Oui c’est ça, vous avez raison. Qu’est-ce que vous me recommendez a faire s’il vous plait? Dois-je effacer la question? C'est une question faible.

Comment: Ou parce qu'il était extrêmement courtois, ou bien c'est un groom ou un garçon d'étage qui fait très bien son métier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il peut être, effectivement timide ou timoré, mais aussi peureux. Cela dépend du contexte duquel est tirée cette phrase.